# Too many buffer headers in vim

Tags: vim, plugins, buffer

Every open buffer have own header and it's very not convinient to work. Is it possible to move(or any other solution) a lot of buffer headers to right horizontal panel?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Which plugin are you using for the buffers?

Comment: What do you mean by "buffer header?" Do you mean the abbreviated filenames at the top of the image you posted? Those are *tab labels* and you can learn more about them under `:help setting-tabline` and `:help setting-guitablabel`

Comment: This is not plugin, as i understand. That screenshot shows actions:
1) gvim filename
2) :badd anotherFile.txt (buffer add) . Not tabnew.

Under "buffer header" I mean all whose file names, like settings-user.html, ddos-view.js and so on. You can see them on the picture. 
Current header for opened file printed with red color.

Answer (score 2):

That list is created by a plugin, probably Airline, so you only have to disable the feature (or the plugin) if you don't want it.

To see an actionable list of buffers, do `:ls`.

Comment: Yes, your right! I forgot about airline tabs. Ok, I will try to find out possibility to move whose airline "tab names" to right horizontal panel. Like NERDTree do.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a function I created some time ago with a bit of help on the internet. Add the following to your .vimrc or init.vim (for neovim) and when you call `:DeleteHiddenBuffers` it would close any hidden buffers from your vim and tidy up your UI.

```
if !exists("*DeleteHiddenBuffers") " Clear all hidden buffers when running 
    function DeleteHiddenBuffers() " Vim with the 'hidden' option
        let tpbl=[]
        call map(range(1, tabpagenr('$')), 'extend(tpbl, tabpagebuflist(v:val))')
        for buf in filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(v:val) && index(tpbl, v:val)==-1')
            silent execute 'bwipeout' buf
        endfor
    endfunction
endif
command! DeleteHiddenBuffers call DeleteHiddenBuffers();
```

Sometime I require hidden buffers since I go back to them. But when I've been working on a project for long hours, it helps clear up some of the unused buffers.

Don't worry this won't close any buffers that are open in the current window, splits, tabs etc. Only if it is invisible it will delete them, this way you won't loose any unsaved work.

Check my vimrc if you wish to pickup any similar utility functions.
https://github.com/arithran/dotfiles/blob/master/.config/nvim/init.vim

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The goal for me is to move that info line to the right part. Let it will look like NERDTree. So to say, vertical list of open files with whose I work right now. Why I want to have it like this? Because this is very annoying if there is too many files(let's say 15) opened. I can't see all of them and always must use bnext bprev till needed file, even thought I have key bindings for bnext and bprev. But if I will have it on the right side in vertical view(like nerdtree do but from the left side), then it will be easier to find each file.